# Class's object initialized in Parent activity re-initialized in child activity

Tags: java, android, object, inheritance, parent-child

I have an object which is initialized in an activity(parent activity) now a child activity which extends the parent activity is re-initializing that object whenever the child activity's onCreate is executed.

**Breakdown:**

1. on parent's `onCreate` a class's object gets initialized under a condition:

```
if(obj == null){
  Init();
}
```

2. a child activity is started (extends parent activity) **at this moment** the parent's onCreate gets called as well due to `super.onCreate()` and somehow it completely ignores the parent's condition to run init() in #1.

Can anyone point me as to how can I get past this situation?

**Update**: anyone..? :(

Comment: Please append the complete code and not only useless snippets.

Comment: @Smutje it's a complex code and follows MVC arch. Can I share the project instead? It's a small project having just the 2xactivity and 1x controller

Comment: No, but at least the two classes which are created and cause the problems are needed to analyze your problem - maybe restrict them to the constructors and the places where the creation happens.

Comment: @Smutje Here's the [parent activity](http://pastebin.com/0GktUgvi) and here's the [child activity](http://pastebin.com/hsyBFjjp) (extends parent activity)

Comment: @blackbelt yep also pls see ^

Comment: I can not see any problem whit the code, what are you expecting?

Comment: @blackbelt well we all know that if B activity extends A then all lifecycle methods of A will be executed in B as well. So, in my case when I create activity B then A's onCreate method gets called as well and the condition of initializing the controller obj is **dis-honored** and the controller gets init'ed again :(

Comment: @blackbelt umm..why had you asked for if the obj is protected or not? :D

Answer (score 2):

So, firstly, `controller` will always be null in `onCreate()`. The reason you're seeing `controller` as null in the child activity is because you're logging it's value *before* you're calling `super.onCreate()` (which calls the parent's `onCreate()` and initializes the controller).

Comment: pls see my above [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436466/classs-object-initialized-in-parent-activity-re-initialized-in-child-activity#comment37809965_24436466) Exactly my point. I don't want the controller's obj to get re-inited. What I don't understand is (leave apart logging the controller's obj in child :p ) why does the `onCreate` of parent activity re-inits the obj at all? :( I have a proper condition there and it was already init'ed before

Comment: When would it ever have been initialized? It is initialized in and only in `onCreate()` of the parent Activity. Launching a subclass of that Activity doesn't launch both the parent and child activity, it only launches the child activity. When the activity is *created* (`onCreate()` is called), you will initialize your controller variable. At no point will `onCreate()` be called twice before your activity is destroyed.

Comment: lol I guess you got me wrong :D What I meant to say is: when the child's `onCreate` is called the parent's `onCreate` is called as well (due to the `super.onCreate()` line) and at that time(inside parent's `onCreate`) it ignores the condition to init/not-to-init the controller's obj and it simply re-inits the obj

Comment: No it doesn't. It goes into the `if (controller == null)` branch, because `controller` will always be null in `onCreate()`.

Comment: so does that mean that the parent activity that first init'ed the obj is now not able to access the controller's obj (at the time the child's onCreate executes the parent's onCreate) ? so, how can I make sure that it does not re-inits or if I can re-init the controller from the child with the referenced obj?

Comment: There are not two objects here. There is only one activity (your child) which *extends* the parent activity. That means that there is only *one* controller instance, which you delegate the instantiation for to the parent class. If that's not clear, what I'm saying is that in your child activity, `this.controller` == `super.controller`.

Comment: Just checked it out and it is pointing to a whole new address. Also, I can't get data out of my model in child activity from `this.controller` :( it definitely is getting instantiated again. Can I make use of `onSaveInstanceState` in parent and get the obj ref to re-init my parent's obj inside child's oncreate? What's the best way possible?